# How to instantiate a class using Spring context.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm really not sure where to start with this because I am extremely new at Spring.

Currently I am instantiating a class like normal,

```
ClassImpl newImpl = new ClassImpl();
```

I want to do this through Spring's context.xml - so I've loaded the class as a bean-

```
<bean id="ClassId" class="ClassImpl"></bean>
```

How do I know instantiate ClassImpl by taking advantage of the fact that I have passed it in as a bean? That is, how do I give newImpl a new ClassImpl by making Spring inject it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do something like:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:" + [package_name/context.xml]);
ClassImpl newImpl = (ClassImpl) ctx.getBean("ClassId")
```

If you're loading it from a context.xml outside your project, I believe you can do

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(path_to_context.xml);
ClassImpl newImpl = (ClassImpl) ctx.getBean("ClassId")
```